# Geoserver WPS - Tiled Barnes Surface with geospatial index

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, leaflet, wps

I'm using [Barnes Surface](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/cartography/rt/barnes.html) to compute a set of points from my PostgreSQL db. The problem is that my whole table is processed for each tile.

I added a geospatial index on my points, how can I tell geoserver to compute only the points present in the bounds of the tile?